# How to add a blinking Image on statusbar while app running in Background state in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios6, background-process, uistatusbar

I need to show a Blinking image that indicates some state of my application while running in background mode like media player showing symbol when playing.

Can any one please help me out !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible in iOS 6 or any other version of iOS. :(

Comment: @GustafRosenblad can I change atleast the color of status bar from red for my recorder application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to do this is currently not allowed by Apple. Maybe next year with iOS 8?

Comment: can I change atleast the color of status bar from red for my recorder application?

Comment: yup you can set it manually in the project settings. but the color is determined by the last row of pixels below the status bar after launch.